# What is the numpy equivalent for R's matrix function?

Tags: python, r, numpy

I'm porting over some R code and you can do something like this (x and centers are matrices):

```
nx <- nrow(x);
nc <- nrow(centers);
matrix(rowSums(x), nrow=nx, ncol=nc)
```

However numpy.matrix does not provide the nrow and ncol arguments. I tried using reshape, but you have to preserve the total number of elements (which does not seem to be the case for the R function).

How would I achieve the same effect in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

Does `rowSums(x) * numpy.ones([nx, nc])` do what you want? It does provide an array instead of a matrix, but that is often better in numpy anyway.